# Prove that each number $a$ in a Pascal's triangle decreased by $1$ is equal to the sum of the numbers within the parallelogram bounded by the sides of

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Prove that each number $a$ in a Pascal's triangle decreased by $1$ is equal to the sum of the numbers within the parallelogram bounded by the sides of the triangle and the diagonalsgoing through $a$ (The numbers in the diagonals are not included )[image]

The above figure shows the representation in a Pascal's triangle as an example .

In order to solve the above problem I proved that: Each number $a$ in Pascal's triangle is equal to the sum of the numbers in the previous right diagonal,  starting from its leftmost number through the number through the number which is located in the left diagonal as $a$.[image]

The above figure represents an example of such an arrangement .

Also I proved the same for left diagonals as well,
Each number $a$ in Pascal's triangle is equal to the sum of the numbers in the previous left diagonal,  starting from its rightmost number through the number through the number which is located in the right  diagonal as $a$.
[image]

Now, how to apply this and then prove the original result?

Comment: What is the source of this problem, please?

Comment: @GerryMyerson This is from the book Mathematical Circles by Dimitri Fomin,  Sergey Genkin and IIa Itenberg  ....

Comment: OK. And what sort of techniques are explained in the chapter that has this question?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Well its from a combinatorics chapter....so yeah the normal ones...I mean it was given in a set of problems....

Comment: Combinatorics is a big, big, big, big topic. I'm trying to get some idea of what kind of tools Fomin et al. expect readers to use. For example, do they work out any similar problems?

Comment: @GerryMyerson They just wrote about Pascal's triangle in that section ...used some basic ideas about the formation of such triangles and the calculations i mean..they provided a proof about the sum in each rows is equal to $2^n$ ways and... they used induction to prove the method's validity(i.e. the nethod of forming Pascals triangles by summing value of each node to get the corresponding node in the next row)...after that it was presented in a set of problems...like i said...

Comment: Have you heard about the "hockey stick" identity ?

Comment: @JeanMarie yes! ...does the problem utilises it while solving it....

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sketch of a proof by induction of your claim. I illustrate the example of $\color{blue}{\binom{7}{3}}=35$.

By the hockey stick identity, you know that
$$
\color{blue}{\binom{7}3}=\color{purple}{\binom{6}3}+\color{red}{\text{sum of red numbers}}
$$
If we apply the inductive hypothesis to $\color{purple}{\binom{6}3}$, we get that
$$
\color{purple}{\binom{6}3}=\text{sum of black numbers}
$$
Combining these,
$$
\color{blue}{\binom{7}3}=\color{red}{\text{sum of red numbers}}+\text{sum of black numbers}
$$
Since the red and black numbers combine to form the required parallelogram for $\color{blue}{\binom 73}$, the proof is complete.

[image]